# useContext undefined react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

estoy teniendo un problema con el hook useContext de react.

El problema es cuando quiero desestructurar los valores del contexto en otro componente, me aparece en consola que no se puede porque los valores son undefined

Context

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const buttonContext = createContext()
const {Provider} = buttonContext

const Context = ({children}) => {

    const[buttonState, setButtonState] = useState(false)
    
    const handleButton = () => {
        setButtonState(!buttonState)
    }

    const contextValue = {
        buttonState : buttonState,
        handleButton : handleButton
    }
    
    return(
        <Provider value={contextValue}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default Context
```

Navbar

```
import buttonContext from "./Context";
const Navbar = () => {

  const {handleButton}  = useContext(buttonContext)

  const sandwich = () => {
    console.log(handleButton);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estas importando el context creado. Estas importando el compenente en sí.

Cambia de `import buttonContext from "./Context";`

a esto `import { buttonContext } from "./Context";`

Comment: Me dí cuenta tarde. Muchísimas gracias!